# EditTextPreference crashes on requestFocus()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am migrating from a PreferenceActivity to a PreferenceFragment (v14) and when I try to tap on my EditTextPreference the app crashes.
The code worked with the PreferenceActivity, which is why I don't really understand why it throws a NullPointerException.

Here is the important part of the code:

```
 private Preference websitePref;
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

    websitePref = findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_key));
    websitePref.setIconSpaceReserved(false);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final String savedWebsite = sharedPrefs.getString(websitePref.getKey(), "");
    websitePref.setSummary(savedWebsite);
...
```

I tried changing the Preference to EditTextPreference and casting it, but I still get the same error:

```
10-05 13:55:36.694 22397-22397/de.test.browserelement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.test.browserelement, PID: 22397
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.EditText.requestFocus()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v14.preference.EditTextPreferenceDialogFragment.onBindDialogView(EditTextPreferenceDialogFragment.java:66)
    at android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(PreferenceDialogFragment.java:149)
    at android.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:410)
    at android.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1435)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1279)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2422)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2201)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2155)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2056)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:719)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Here is my EditTextPreference in my preferences.xml:

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/preference_default"
        android:key="@string/preference_key"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/preference_title"
        android:dependency="@string/sperr_key"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
```

Comment: please check you initialized `EditText` perfectly or not

Comment: views are not created when onCreateView() is called. Check where you have called requestFocus and move it to onViewCreated()

Comment: My problem is that I never called requestFocus() myself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For some reason it does not set the dialog layout by default.

Try casting it to EditTextPreference and add this line of code:
websitePref.setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_dialog_edittext);